# Vimeo iframe inside of another iframe

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I want to imbed Vimeo Iframe in a html page. I use another Iframe to display that Vimeo iframe video, however I do have some issues with the output.

I can hoover the video, but not push the button play?

What am i doing wrong?

Please take a look at www.sebastiankornum.com, go to Blog and the try Video Test blogpost.

The problem is primarily in Firefox.

Thanks - Klaus

//UPDATE
Here is my section where i have an Iframe.

```
       <section class="st-panel" id="st-panel-3" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="content" style="width:100%; position: absolute; left:0%; right:0%; bottom: 0; text-align:middle;">
          <a href="http://sebastiankornum.com/sebs-update.aspx" target="blogFrame"><h2 style="left:18%;">Latest news</h2></a>
          <iframe src="http://sebastiankornum.com/sebs-update.aspx" style="border:0px; overflow:auto;" name="blogFrame" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: It is acutally just an Vimeo Iframe inside of another Iframe. Then there is som CSS.

Comment: No one have a clue whats wrong?